# SQLite Adding information to database

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't know what is wrong with my code. What I am trying to do is to save the information enter by the user in the database. Please help me.

This the code that passes all the information entered by the user. This is in my SignupActivity.

```
databaseAdapter.saveUserInfo(Lastname,Firstname,MiddleInitial,Username, Password);
```

Now, here is the code in my DatabaseAdapter where all the information is to be passed.

```
public long saveUserInfo(String Lastname, String Firstname,String MiddleInitial,String Username,String Password)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, Firstname);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_LASTNAME, Lastname);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_MI, MiddleInitial);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_USERNAME, Username);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_PASSWORD, Password);
    return dbSqlite.insert(Constants.DATABASE_TABLE_USER_NAME_WITH_USERNAME_PASSWORD, null, contentValues);
}
```

Am I missing something? here's the error in my logcat

```
05-23 16:37:15.080: W/dalvikvm(18203): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x402ac760)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at com.example.customercare.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:65)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3131)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12035)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
05-23 16:37:15.085: E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have to learn how to read the logcat. You have a NullPointerException thrown at the line 65 of `SignUpActivity.java`. Check on this line if all the variables you're using are well initialized.

Comment: Something is null, at com.example.customercare.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:65) ... like it says.

Comment: from your code, i'd guess databaseAdapter is null ...

Comment: have you initialized  dbSqlite??     SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `dbSqlite` is initalized,
maybe you can write like this.

```
//enter code here
public void save(Person person){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", person.getName());
    values.put("phone", person.getPhone());
    values.put("amount", person.getAmount());
    db.insert("person", null, values);
}
```

Maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please make ensure your dbSqlite is opening.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the `dbSqlite` initialization.

```
public long saveUserInfo(String Lastname, String Firstname,String MiddleInitial,String   Username,String Password)
{
    dbSqlite = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, Firstname);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_LASTNAME, Lastname);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_MI, MiddleInitial);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_USERNAME, Username);
    contentValues.put(Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_PASSWORD, Password);
    return dbSqlite.insert(Constants.DATABASE_TABLE_USER_NAME_WITH_USERNAME_PASSWORD, null, contentValues);
}
```

Comment: thanks @MDMalik I've initializes the dbSqlite but I cant use java.lang.NullPointerException. Honestly I don't know how :( help me please ..

Comment: @dolphinately just make sure that your code is reaching the adapter funcationality. You can do it by using `Log.i` and viewing it in `LogCat` just so you know where exactly is it crashing